# How to filter list of tuples(x,y) where y is not contained in another list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of tuples with (string,int) pairs.

I also have a list of int's.

I want to filter the list of tuples by the following psuedocode:

```
l1 = list of touples(string,int)
l2 = list of int's

for tuple in l1:
   if tuple(int) is in l2
      remove tuple from l1
```

For example, lets say

```
l1=[("one",1),("two",5),("three",8),("bla",11)]

l2=[1,8]
```

Output would be:

```
[("two",5),("bla",11)]
```

Hopefully thats clear.

Comment: Usually it is easier to create a new empty list and fill it with the tuples you want to keep (or use a list comprehension to do that).

Comment: You shouldn't remove while iterating, you can easily skip elements. Use a list comp, something like `[i for i in l1 if i[1] not in l2]`

Comment: Just reassign `l1 = [i for i in l1 if i[1] not in l2]`

Comment: What @yatu said, but I recommend convert `l2` to `set` first, to speed up searching.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should create a set of the filter values, and then use list comprehension for constructing a new list:

```
l1 = [("one",1),("two",5),("three",8),("bla",11)]
l2 = [1,8]
# Make a set for efficient 
s2 = set(l2)
# List comprehension for including only tuples where integer is not in s2 (l2)
l3 = [t for t in l1 if t[1] not in s2]

print(l3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
output = [(key, value) for key, value in l1 if value not in set(l2)]

print(output)
```

Output:

```
[('two', 5), ('bla', 11)]
```

Comment: Conversion to set (`set(l2)`) will occur on every iteration.  Probably not what you were aiming to do as it's not a performance enhancement.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use either filter or list comprehensions, like this:

```
filtered_tuples = [t for t in l1 if t[1] not in l2]
```

If you feel more comfortable using for loops, you could just do:

```
filtered_tuples = []
for t in l1:
    if t[1] not in l2:
        filtered_tuples.append(t)
```

Whenever you have an iterable, you can use the in keyword to check if an object is somewhere inside that iterable.

Answer (score 0):

A functional approach would be to use the [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) built-in function

```
filter(lambda x: x[1] in l2, l1)
```

This would return an iterator instead of a list, although for a large enough `l1` you would probably want to use a generator/iterator anyway